# What is the value returned by theme_get_registry, and why is it not NULL?

Tags: theming

I was going through Drupal code, and in the theme.inc file I found something that I couldn't understand. On `theme()`, I see the following code:

```
if (!isset($hooks)) {
  init_theme();
  $hooks = theme_get_registry();
}
```

`theme_get_registry()` is defined as follows:

```
function theme_get_registry($registry = NULL) {

  static $theme_registry = NULL;
  if (isset($registry)) {
    $theme_registry = $registry;
  }
  return $theme_registry;
}
```

I found the function is calling without any parameter, and the default parameter is `NULL`, but when I use `print_r($registry)` in the first line of the function `theme_get_registry()`, I get the values popped out; I assume the value should be `NULL` because it is not passing any value, and default value is `NULL`, from where `$registry` got values in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from `theme_get_registry()` is initialized by [_theme_set_registry()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_theme_set_registry/6), which is called by [_theme_load_registry()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_theme_load_registry/6), which is called by [_init_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_init_theme/6), called by [init_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/init_theme/6).

```
function _theme_set_registry($registry) {
  // Pass through for setting of static variable.
  return theme_get_registry($registry);
}
```

`init_theme()` is called from [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6), right before calling `theme_get_registry()`.

```
  $args = func_get_args();
  $hook = array_shift($args);

  static $hooks = NULL;
  if (!isset($hooks)) {
    init_theme();
    $hooks = theme_get_registry();
  }
```

The value used by `theme_get_registry()` (`$theme_registry`) is a static value; this means that the value `theme_get_registry()` gets from `_theme_set_registry()` is then returned all the times `theme_get_registry()` is called. `NULL` is the default value for `$theme_registry`, until `$theme_registry = $registry` is executed, and the calling function uses a value different from the default one.

To notice that the declaration of a static variable is different from the declaration of other local variables used by a function.

If I declare a variable as `static $registry = NULL` it doesn't mean the variable is always set to `NULL`. The constant value used in the declaration is the value assigned to the variable when it is initialized; the second time the function is called, its static variables are not initialized anymore, but they retain the value they had in the previous call of the function.
As reported in [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
function test() {
  $a = 0;
  echo $a;
  $a++;
}
```

> This function is quite useless since every time it is called it sets $a to 0 and prints 0. The `$a++` which increments the variable serves no purpose since as soon as the function exits the `$a` variable disappears. To make a useful counting function which will not lose track of the current count, the $a variable is declared static:

```
function test() {
  static $a = 0;
  echo $a;
  $a++;
}
```

> Now, `$a` is initialized only in first call of function and every time the `test()` function is called it will print the value of `$a` and increment it.

Comment: And here drupal uses [static variables in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) for $theme_registry. So $theme_registry will be initialized only first time

Comment: I added a note about PHP static variables used functions. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: if (!isset($hooks)) 
  {
    init_theme();
 print_r($hooks); //prints nothing
    $hooks = theme_get_registry(); //no values passing, value of the variable $registry become null,
 print_r($hooks); //print values
  }

Comment: @Thomas No, the value of `$registry` doesn't become `NULL`.